# After Press e.keycode 13(enter key) console value printed multiple time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written one Small script. By clicking the tab, it will show the console value `"hotspot div is focused"` then if I hit enter in the same div it will show the console value `"Enter key is pressed"`. First time it's working totally fine. But the problem is if  I click the tab second time and hit enter, in the console `"Enter key is pressed"` this value showing twice. And that value increased every time. How can I prevent it and make it triggered once each time without page load?

Code is attached below

```js
$( ".main-nav__menu-hotspot" ).focus(function() {
  console.log("hotspot div is focused");
  $(".main-nav__menu-hotspot").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      console.log("Enter key is pressed");
      $('.main-nav-overlay').toggleClass('main-nav-overlay--menu-open');
      $('.main-nav--gct').toggleClass('main-nav--menu-open');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-nav__menu-hotspot" tabindex="0">menu</div>

<div class="main-nav-overlay">
overlay
</div>
<div class = "main-nav--gct">
nav
</div>
```

Comment: Because you're binding the `keypress` event every time `.main-nav__menu-hotspot` gets focused. You need to put this code outside the `focus` event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is creating a new `keypress` event listener, every time the `$( ".main-nav__menu-hotspot" ).focus()`  event listener is triggered.

e.g. if you hover over the menu 4 times (or whatever triggers the `focus` event), it'll create 4 `keypress` event listeners.  So when you do the keypress, it'll execute 4 times.

Move the `keypress` event listener creation out of the other one:

```
$( ".main-nav__menu-hotspot" ).focus(function() {
  console.log("hotspot div is focused");

});

$(".main-nav__menu-hotspot").keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log("Enter key is pressed");
    $('.main-nav-overlay').toggleClass('main-nav-overlay--menu-open');
    $('.main-nav--gct').toggleClass('main-nav--menu-open');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```